# animated loading icon not animating on jquery show

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not sure i am doing  this correctly. 
i have this snippet of code. in the css loadingDiv is display:none.
so when i click on the li, the loadingDiv shows and the form is called, but the animated gif doesn't animate. if i set the display: to block just to make sure , it animates as you would expect but of course i want that div hidden until the click.  Is there a better way to do this?

```
  $(function() {
       $( ".tc-group-li" ).live("click", function(event){
           var $item = $( this ),
               $target = $( event.target );

           $('.loadingDiv', $item).show();
           $('.tc-group-name', $item).html('');
           $('#gid').val($item.attr('id'));
           $('#tc-form').submit();
       });
   });

<li  class="tc-group-li" id="<%=TcGroupDesc.getID(x)%>" >
     <div class="loadingDiv">&nbsp;</div>
     <div class='tc-group-name'>
        <%=TcGroupDesc.getGroupName(x)%>
     </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Place an animated gif inside of the loading div.  I assume you are using a background image.

`<div class="loadingDiv"><img src="loading.gif" alt="loading" /></div>`

Update

```
.loadingDiv img {display:none}

<div class="loadingDiv">
<img src="loading.gif" class="load1" alt="loading" />
<img src="loading.gif" class="load2" alt="loading" />
<img src="loading.gif" class="load3" alt="loading" />
</div>

 $('.loadingDiv img.load1', $item).show();  //  $('.loadingDiv img.load1', $item).show().parent().show();
 $('.loadingDiv', $item).show();
```

or

```
<div class="loadingDiv">
<img src="loading.gif" class="loading" alt="loading" />

</div>

 $('.loadingDiv img', $item).attr('src', 'loading2.gif');
 $('.loadingDiv', $item).show();
```

Comment: The only problem is i have different style sheets with different loading gifs. How would you handle that?
Thanks for your help

Comment: The easiest and maybe not the most elegant way is to put them all in the loading div and show the one you want.. I am updating the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) and [.fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) instead of .show() and .hide().